# Prove that n=o(2^{f(n)})?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, complexity-theory

**Please Note:** In this question log (n) is to the base of 2.

I know that `f(n)=omega(log(n))` - in other words for **every** `c>0: f(n)>=c*log(n)`
*(starting from a specific location)*

I want to prove that `n=o(2^{f(n)})` - in other words for **every** `d>0: n<=d*2^{f(n)}` *(starting from a specific location)*

How may I prove this?

---

**What I did?**

I tried using limits which you can find here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3895906/prove-that-the-following-limit-is-0

but it seems impossible so I'm trying to solve it the traditional way but get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the premise for `c = 2`, there is an `N0 > 0` such that `f(n) >= 2 log(n)` for all `n > N0`. By monotonicity of `y = 2^x` this is equivalent to `2^f(n) >= n^2` for all `n > N0`.

For any `d > 0` there is an `N1 > 0` such that `n^2 >= n/d` for all `n > N1` since the quadratic `n^2` grows faster than any linear `n/d`.

Combining the two inequalities, `n/d <= n^2 <= 2^f(n)` for all `n > max(N0, N1)`.

Comment: your first sentence is incorrect, please note I said for every c>0 so you can't decide which c to choose

Comment: that's the definition of omega and small o in complexity, the above statements should be true for every  c and d bigger than 0. (starting from a specific location) I used d to prevent duplicate of the same letter